# Descargar archivos CSV y excel desde mi sitio web

Tags: php

Cordial saludo. En mi sitio web tengo tablas de datos que los usuarios pueden visualizar, pero la mayoría de ellos, les gusta tenerlos en Excel para hacerle cálculos adicionales.
Tengo entendido que puedo crear un botón que permita descargarlos en CSV o Excel.

Me gustaría que mi dieran una inducción en como hacerlo, teniendo presente que los datos están en SQL SERVER.

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes agregar lo que has intentado?

Comment: Hola, por favor pon más información, como por ejemplo el código de la tabla, pero aun así te pregunto usas DataTables??

Comment: Cordial saludo. Agradezco a Bicho y Daniel por sus observaciones. Lo voy a tener muy presente en mis próximas consultas. Debido a que soy nuevo en la programacion, siempre pienso que al hacer una pregunta, me va a enviar un tutorial o algo par hacer que me ayude, pero entiendo que debo compartirles codigo e indicarles que e realizado. Nuevamente gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con este código puede incluir el botón que me permitía descargar una tabla en excel desde la pagina web.

```
<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('TableCombustibleAno','combustible')" value="Exportar a Excel">
        <table id="TableCombustibleAno" style="margin: 0 auto;">
            <caption>Resumen año</caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="TablaCampos">
                    <td>OPERACION</td>
                    <td>CONSUMO_REAL</td>
                    <td>CONSUMO_ESPERADO</td>
                    <td>PORCENTAJE</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <?php if(!$stml1) { ?>
                <tr>
                     <td colspan="6">No hay datos para mostrar</td>
                </tr>
            <?php }
            else {
                while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stml1)) { ?>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="TablaRegistros">
                             <td><?php echo $row['operacion'];?></td>
                             <td><?php echo number_format($row['consumo_real']);?></td>
                             <td><?php echo number_format($row['consumo_esperado']);?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $row['porcentage']*100,'%';?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
            <?php
                }//Fin while
                }//Fin if 
            ?> 
        </table>
```